# PHP get hex value (not the string representation, actually hex)

Tags: php, string, types, hex

I have the hex representation and I'm trying to convert this to the type of hex. For example if you execute:

```
echo "\xFF\xAA";
echo '<br>';
$first    = "FF";
$second   = "AA";
echo "\x$first\x$second";
die();
```

The result you get is:
[image: code output]

So the first line is weird symbols. This indicates to me this is actually of type hex. Where the second result although is valid representations of hex, they are in fact not actually hex.

So my question is how can I make the actual result hex? I want to be able to use a variable as the representation but actually convert it to hex. (I want line two to show up as symbols)

Comment: The first line is what the bytes look like using the encoding your website uses (usually utf8 or iso-8859-1). The second line is essentially just the string `"\xFF\xAA"` and has little to do with hex encoding. What do you mean by "actual result hex"? And what symbols are you expecting to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **hex2bin** — Decodes a hexadecimally encoded binary string

```
<?php
    $hex = hex2bin("6578616d706c65206865782064617461");
    echo $hex;
?>
```

Output:

> example hex data

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.hex2bin.php

So just use

```
echo hex2bin("$first$second");
```